# Proving a function $f$ is not differentiable at an unkown point $a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let's say I have an arbitrary function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and I want to prove that it is not differentiable at some **unknown** point $a$. Emphasis must be placed on the *unknown* part as that is the very basis of this question.

To do this we want to show it's derivative $f'(x)$ does not exist at that point $a$.

Now the standard *rigorous* approach would be to use the formal definition of a derivative to find $f'(x)$, and then show that $a \not\in D_{f'(x)}$, where $D_{f'(x)}$ is the domain of $f'(x)$. However since $a$ is unknown, it's seems a bit sloppy to use the formal definition in it's standard form to compute the derivative, i.e.

**1. Standard Approach**

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to \ 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

***Problem***: I argue this approach would be non-rigorous as $\exists \ a \in D_{f(x)}$, *(there exists a number $a$ in the domain of the original function), where this limit in the formal definition doesn't even exist*. Although it will compute the correct derivative, the process in which it's done seems hap-hazard.

I think it would be more rigorous to compute $f'(x)$ for $x > a$ and $f'(x)$ for $x < a$, (i.e. computing the 'left' and 'right' hand derivatives, but I hate calling them that)

**2. 'Left'/'Right' Derivative Approach**

$$f'(x>a) = \lim_{h \to \ 0^{+}} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
$$f'(x<a) = \lim_{h \to \ 0^{-}} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

***Problem***: This approach becomes horribly over-complicated, if you have a set of values $S$, where $f'(x)$ does not exist, i.e. $S= \{k\ |\ k\in D_{f(x)} \land \not\exists f'(k) \}$

---

I will give a concrete example to show what I'm getting at.

**Example :** Given $f(x) = x|x|$, for what values of $x$ is $f$ not differentiable

$$\begin{align}f'(x) = |x| + \frac{x^2}{|x|} &&& (1)\end{align}$$

We could simply take the derivative of $f(x)$ in a non-rigorous way using the rules of differentiation, as we've done above, and immediately we can see that $f'(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$.

But that's not the problem, the problem is how do we get to $(1)$ in the most rigorous way possible (using the formal definition of a derivative), without reaching the problems I outlined in the opening half of this post?

Answer (score 0):

As $|x|$ is *defined* by a case distinction, you are more or less forced to evaluate $f'$ via case distinction. That is, for $x>0$ we have $f(x)=x|x|=x^2$ and for $x<0$ we have $f(x)=x|x|=-x^2$ (whereas for $x=0$, both variants could be used if desired). As $\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid x>0\,\}$ is open, we find that $f'$ equals the derivative of $x\mapsto x^2$ there. Similarly, $\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid x<0\,\}$ is open so that $f'$ equals the derivative of $x\mapsto -x^2$ there.
Unfortunately, neither of these cases tells us anything about the derivative at $x=0$. So without further ado, a direct computation might be called for:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h|h|-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}|h|=0$$
We conclude that $f$ is differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$. Also, we can combine our findings ($f'(x)=2x$ for $x>0$, $f'(x)=-2x$ for $x<0$, $f'(0)=0$) into 
$$f'(x)=2|x|. $$

Comment: Using the other definition of the absolute value $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ I get $f'(x) = |x| + \frac{x^2}{|x|}$, which if you *do not* open up into via case distinction, implies $f'(0)$ is not well defined. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, your answer is correct as I just realized, but why the difference in what the derivative implies when using the two different definitions of the absolute value?

Comment: Also I noticed you said $f(x) = x^2$ for $x>0$. However why is it not $f(x) = x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ as per the case definition of the absolute value : $$|x| = \begin{cases}x & \text{if} & x\geq0 \\ -x & \text{if} & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: @Perturbative To answer your question, the reason your formula fails is because the product rule only works when $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable. In this case, one of the functions in your product is not differentiable at $0$, and hence the formula one obtains via the product rule may fail at that point.

Comment: Your different representation of the modulus does not show that $f'$ is not well defined, it shows that nothing can be said about $f'(0)$ *using this representation* of the modulus. Note that $\sqrt$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, hence the chain rule cannot be applied (and canno be blamed for nonsense obtained by applying it anyway). The failure of a tool to determine a derivative need not always be caused by the nonexistence of the derivative, it may also be the case that the tool is simply not applicable. - I treated $x=0$ as special case because I needed open sets where $f$ equals $x^2$.